# Multiple SQL commands executed via "ExecuteReader" in a system I can only manipulate SQL statements

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have to configure a system which provides me with an area to input SQL statements.

It is important to notice that we cannot modify the system we are configuring.

I believe the system was built in C# (.net for sure but C# is a guess).

Any way, I'm trying to create a script that would:

1. create a temporary table
2. create a temporary procedure (which inserts into the table created)
3. call the temporary procedure 4 times
4. Read the temp table as a response to the system's call.

Something like:

```
CREATE Procedure #myTempProcedure(
  @param1 nvarchar(max)
) as 
begin
  insert #tempTable (col1, col2) select aCol, bCol from table2 where col2 = @param1;
end;


CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(col1 nvarchar(512),
(col2 nvarchar(512));

EXEC #myTempProcedure N'val1';
EXEC #myTempProcedure N'val2';
EXEC #myTempProcedure N'val3';
EXEC #myTempProcedure N'val4';

select col1, col2 from #tempTable;
```

The system is very likely executing my script via C# `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` method. As I can simulate the problem in a simple C# application I created.

The problem is that when executing this script, the system (or SQL Server) assumes the procedure body to be the entire script and seems to disregard my `;` in line 6 of the example above. My intention with this `;` was to flag the end of the procedure creation.

Executing this script in Management studio requires a `GO` to be placed in line 7 of the example above, otherwise the same problem reported by the system would happen in Management Studio.

Is there a `GO` equivalent I could use in this script to get it to work??

Or is there a better way to script this??

I have a background in Oracle, and I'm still leaning SQL server usual tricks... The System accepts multiple commands apart from the create procedure here, So I'm inclined to believe there is a SQL Server trick I could use here.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that syntactically there is no way to create a procedure and then do something after it in the same batch.  The compiler doesn't know where it ends, and things like semi-colon don't fix it (because semi-colon only terminates a statement, not a batch).

Using dynamic SQL, (and fixing one syntax error) this works:

```
EXEC('
    CREATE Procedure ##myTempProcedure(
        @param1 nvarchar(max)
    ) as 
    begin
      insert #tempTable (col1, col2) select aCol, bCol from table2 where col2 = @param1;
    end;
');


CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
    col1 nvarchar(512),
    col2 nvarchar(512)
);

EXEC ##myTempProcedure N'val1';
EXEC ##myTempProcedure N'val2';
EXEC ##myTempProcedure N'val3';
EXEC ##myTempProcedure N'val4';

select col1, col2 from #tempTable;

EXEC('DROP PROC ##myTempProcedure;');
```

Comment: Barry, you are spot on! Wrapping with the `EXEC` worked very well. As you commented this is just a small portion of the procedure script. Thank you!

Comment: @TheFabio and RBarryYoung: The only issue that I can see here is that it is not "thread-safe" due to the global temp proc. If called by two processes it will bomb on the 2nd call. However, since the definition of the temp proc is always the same, then it could be fixed simply by putting an `IF NOT EXISTS` around the `EXEC('CREATE PROC...` and then remove the `EXEC('DROP...`. Then, if a 2nd process does start, it will share the global temp proc but the data will go into the non-shared, local temp table :-).

Comment: Hi Srutzky. Not  sure where you are coming from... I actually use the exec call over 1000 times, maybe with 10 parallel calls, it works fine. I don

Comment: as a curiosity, I'm not actually executing a drop at all... I believe both the temp table and temp proc  get dropped when the connection drops

Comment: @srutzky i am not sure what the persistence of global temp procs is.  Like Fabio, it appeared to me that it was being cleaned up post batch, even without my drop, which suggests that it may not have the same lifetime and visibility rules as global temp tables.  I cannot test it today though, and an existence check my be the safest thing...

Comment: Careful with using any ## tables its shared on different connections also. so you might step on some ones space when you do a truncate or a drop. avoid this ## if possible. there is a reason RB has given you this step, is because a exec sql has its own inner session and will not help with the session. think of it as a private scope. when you do any exec ' create #table ' you will not be able to access in the parent scope. once the exec is complete the table is no more there.

Comment: @TheFabio and RBarryYoung: I'm coming from North Carolina ;-). I think your first reply to my comment got cut off. And I'm sure this small code works fast enough to rarely see a problem. I am just suggesting how to reduce the possibility of running into this potential race condition. I have just tested this and Global temp procs are removed when the session that created them ends, whether or not they were executed within a transaction in another session (unlike global temp tables which are kept alive if a transaction in another session is referencing them). So once the `IF NOT EXISTS` (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) is added, the only potential issue would be if the session that created the global temp proc ends and removes the proc while another session has already moved past the `CREATE PROC` statement. I suppose the only way to completely side-step this issue would be to use `NEWID()` to create a temp proc name dynamically so that there cannot be any naming collisions. Then you just need to put the `EXEC ##proc` into Dynamic SQL, and you don't need the `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @bhushanvinay `EXEC` does not have its own session. It simply creates a sub-process, just like `sp_executesql`. Also, nobody is talking about global temp tables. The table shown in this answer is a local temp table (i.e. `#temp`, not `##temp`). And the reason RBarryYoung is suggesting a global temporary _procedure_ is precisely due to it surviving beyond the end of that sub-process.

Comment: @TheFabio and RBarryYoung: I added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34476719/577765) that is a variation of the variation I mentioned in my last comment. It won't work in all cases, but should work in this case and does get around both of the potential issues of working with global temp procs.

Answer (score 0):

1) please look at the rights on the server you many have some issues with if you cannot change or add anything to the system.
ie., Create procedure statements.

2) you could do a small exercise

open a connection object using the SqlConnection()
keep the connection open till you execute all you statements

ie., a) create your #table 
     b) execute your insert statement.
     c) select * from your #table
this should get you back the data you are intending to get back from your temp table note i skipped the entire proc here.

Comment: That is not the problem here.

Comment: then what is the problem? do you want to try the SMO connection that should give you a way into executing statements with go statement.

Comment: The problem is that syntactically there is no way to create a procedure and then do something after it in the same batch execution.

Comment: should have taken out the entire proc as its just a wrap to insert staement.

Comment: Actually, the OP indicated that it is just an example.  The real proc is likely much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating stored procedure, you can execute sql statements delimited by semi colon. You can execute multiple statements this way. Also if you want to create a temp table and load it with data, you can use the same connection with multiple sql commands.

Comment: That is not the problem here.

Comment: Hmm.. I understand that Fabio wants to create procedure on every connection, and drop it at the end. And that is as good as you execute set of sql statement. I am not aware of other benefits of that approach unless you could tell me one pls.

Comment: The OP is already executing multiple statements separated by semicolons, that is not the problem for which they are requesting help.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the proc definition doesn't change, *and* that there is no real harm in the proc existing beyond the end of this particular process, it could just as easily be a regular (i.e. non-temporary) Stored Procedure that just happens to exist in `tempdb`. The benefit of using a regular Stored Procedure created in `tempdb` is that you do not need to worry about potential name collisions when using global temporary stored procedures. The script simply needs to ensure that the stored procedure exists. But there is no need to remove the Stored Procedure manually or have it automatically cleaned up.

The following code is adapted from @RBarryYoung's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34464184/577765):

```sql
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.myTempProcedure') IS NULL)
BEGIN
  USE [tempdb];

  EXEC('
      CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myTempProcedure(
          @param1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
      ) AS 
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tempTable (col1, col2)
          SELECT aCol, bCol
          FROM table2
          WHERE col2 = @param1;
      END;
');
END;

CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
    col1 NVARCHAR(512),
    col2 NVARCHAR(512)
);

EXEC tempdb.dbo.myTempProcedure N'val1';
EXEC tempdb.dbo.myTempProcedure N'val2';
EXEC tempdb.dbo.myTempProcedure N'val3';
EXEC tempdb.dbo.myTempProcedure N'val4';

SELECT col1, col2 FROM #tempTable;
```

The only difference here is that a non-temporary Stored Procedure does not execute in the context of the current database, but instead, like any other non-temporary Stored Procedure, runs within the context of the database where it exists, which in this case is `tempdb`. So the table that is being selected from (i.e. `table2`) needs to be fully-qualified. This means that if the proc needs to run in multiple databases and reference objects local to each of them, then this approach is probably not an option.

Comment: This is not an option... The system I'm using would require additional QA effort for a non-temporary object. If the procedure used is temporary the auditors do not worry about it... Thank you anyway

Comment: @TheFabio That's fine. I was just giving another option. It might help someone else, or maybe just knowing how this works might help you on something else later. But for the record, creating a regular stored procedure in `tempdb` is still mostly "temporary" since `tempdb` is re-built upon each server restart. So if that NT service for SQL Server ever starts up again, then the proc created by this process will not exist :-). So while it might not be _officially_ "temporary", it is certainly not permanent.